# Disabling all buttons with Google Web Toolkit

Tags: gwt

How I can disable all buttons?
I try `RootPanel.getBodyElement().getElementsByTagName("button")` and then I iterate it but... I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it -

`NodeList<Element> e=RootPanel.getBodyElement().getElementsByTagName("button");`
and then -

`for(int i=0;i<e.getLength(); i++) e.getItem(i).setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");`

Comment: Could you put other ways, please? I have problems enabling buttons in some cases.

Comment: e.getItem(i).removeAttribute("disabled");

Comment: The other way would be to track all the buttons in your GWT code, and disable them there. Not as quick or easy as this. What problems are you facing enabling buttons?